# Es posible crear tablas dinámicamente a partir de una lista de nombres con EntityFramework C#?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Tengo una lista de nombres para tablas; todas las tablas deberían tener exactamente las mismas propiedades, es decir, siguen el mismo modelo. La razon de crear diferentes tablas con las mismas propiedades y no hacer una sola tabla es por temas de concurrencia, ya que se tendrían muchas escrituras y lecturas a una misma tabla. y para evitar eso se piensa crear tablas independientes.

alguien ha pasado por un problema similar? como lo ha solucionado?
estoy utilizando .net 6

Comment: 3 cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes. 2. Múltiples tablas con las mismas propiedades para manejar concurrencia es una idea muy poco común, inclusive creo que es ineficiente y costosa en término de procesamiento y almacenamiento. 3. ¿Has considerado leer la documentación oficial? En ella existe ese caso donde emplean un campo "Row Version" para manejar la concurrencia. Aquí la documentación: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations y en español: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations .Saludos.

Comment: Y porque piensas que por estar en tablas diferentes vas a tener menos problemas de lectura y escritura??? el disco es uno sola... otra cosa es que tu db permita particionar, o tengas un RAID...

Comment: Andrew, tienes un error de concepto eso que quieres hacer es una solucion malisima, y aumenta considerablemente la complejidad del sistema